# returning last 5 rounds and passing them into where in select

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

```
    create or replace function get_last_5_rounds(i_party_id in number) return SYS_REFCURSOR as  
      resault_set SYS_REFCURSOR;
       v_round VAR_ROUND:=VAR_ROUND();

 begin  
SELECT round
    BULK COLLECT INTO v_round  
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT session_id,
        ROUND
      FROM super_six_tickets
      where party_id = i_party_id
      ORDER BY session_id DESC
      )
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 5;
 OPEN RESAULT_SET for  
      select rp.session_id, s.symbol_name_in_number ball_number,
             rp.position ,
             rp.additional_symbol
      from   rp_deck rp,
             symbols s
      where  session_id MEMBER OF v_round 
      and    s.game_name_id in  38
      and    s.id = rp.card_name_id
      and    s.client_id = 1
      and    rp.position < 36
     order by rp.position ;  
  RETURN RESAULT_SET;
end get_last_5_rounds;
```

[image]

I have a function which will return ball_number, position from last 5 rounds (p_round).

In first select I get 5 rounds, but I am also getting error on the second select:

> an INTO clause is expected in this select

How will I pass all rounds from first select and separate them with `,` (comma) to include them IN clause ?

Thanks!

EDITED:

Now i m getting this:

[image]

I need to separate all positions and ball number for unique session ID. Now i am  getting sorted by position . 
How can i do that?

Comment: Or to include first select IN clause ..

Comment: Is this the result of your sys_refcursor ? Can you post how exactly your output should look like.

Comment: Its good now. i m getting https://imgur.com/a/Iep3j6i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In first select I get 5 rounds, but I am also getting error on the
>   second select:

Even your first select will throw error since you are trying to put multiple rows in a single dimension variable. In your case either you need to `loop` and and populate your variables or you need to create  a `collection` and do `bulk` operation to fit all the rows.

> How will I pass all rounds from first select and separate them with ,
>   (comma) to include them IN clause ?

You would need a `nested` table to achieve your requirement. See below the working code and read inline explaination for understanding.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE super_six_tickets(session_id NUMBER,ROUND NUMBER);
/
CREATE TABLE  rp_deck (session_id NUMBER, position NUMBER,additional_symbol VARCHAR2(10));
/
CREATE TABLE symbols(symbol_name_in_number NUMBER);
/
 --Create a type of number to hold the result of you first query.
CREATE TYPE VAR_ROUND IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  FUNCTION get_last_5_rounds
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  AS
    resault_set SYS_REFCURSOR;

    --Initialization of varaible of nested table type 
    v_round VAR_ROUND:=VAR_ROUND();

BEGIN

    SELECT round
    BULK COLLECT INTO v_round  --<--Fetching the rounds information in the variable
    FROM
      (SELECT DISTINCT session_id,
        ROUND
      FROM super_six_tickets
      ORDER BY session_id DESC
      )
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 5;

--Opening Sys_refcursor to get the result.
    OPEN RESAULT_SET for   
    SELECT s.symbol_name_in_number ball_number,
           rp.position,
           rp.additional_symbol
    FROM rp_deck rp,
         symbols s
    WHERE rp.session_id MEMBER OF v_round --<-- checking In clause. 
    -- You can use this as well. However `MEMBER OF` clause is provided by Oracle to handle such situations.  
    --> rp.session_id in (Select column_value from table(v_round)) 
    ORDER BY rp.position ASC;

    RETURN RESAULT_SET;

  END get_last_5_rounds;
```